# Unity 2D collisions with prefabs not working on phone

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, touch, collision-detection

I'm having a bit of a problem with OnTriggerEnter when I'm using my mobile as a test device. 
I have some touch code that successfully lets me drag objects around the screen.
I am then having the objects collide with other objects on the screen.

This was working perfectly until I turned the objects into prefabs. ( I'm needing to do this as the objects are being randomly generated at runtime)

Now, I can still move the objects around the screen but they no longer collide with the other objects, which are also prefabs. It does however still work fine when running it on my laptop in the unity editor.

All my objects have colliders on them with trigger checked, and the moving objects have rigidbodies.

On trigger enter code

```
public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    Debug.Log ("here");
    Debug.Log(this.gameObject.tag +"is this");
    Debug.Log(other.gameObject.tag + "is other");
    if (this.gameObject.tag == other.gameObject.tag) 
    {
        Debug.Log("here2)");
        Reftomanager.miniGameScore++;
        Reftomanager.updateScore();
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
}
```

touch code

```
    if (Input.touchCount > 0) 
    {


        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

        switch(touch.phase)
        {

        case TouchPhase.Began:
                Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (touch.position);

                if (Physics.Raycast(ray,out hit)) 
                {
                    thisObject = hit.collider.gameObject;
                    touchPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (touch.position);
                    if(thisObject.name!="circle")
                    {
                    draggingMode = true;
                    }
                }


                break;

        case TouchPhase.Moved: 
            if (draggingMode) 
            {
                touchPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (touch.position);
                newCentre = touchPos;
                thisObject.transform.position = touchPos;
            }
            break;


        case TouchPhase.Ended: 

            draggingMode = false;

        break;
        }
    }


}
```

I'm completely stumped so any help would be amazing.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just got this same error recently.  I suggest using

```
If(other.gameObject.CompareTag ("YourTagName"))
```

Also if you recently added a tag or edited any tags, I found that unity has a bug where your tags will not register on your android build unless you restart unity.

GL.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem as you did, closed Unity, reopened, built and it worked. Thanks a lot. For anyone else who wants to know, I'm using Unity 2018.2.0f

Comment: using Unity 2019.6f1. and same problem occurred after adding some new tags. and yes restarting unity is the only option. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since your using 3D colliders, is it possible that the position you are assigning them is different? Touch.position is a Vector2, which means [ScreenToWorldPoint](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html) would be using 0 for z. If you are using a Vector3 with a z value other than 0 to get the world point in the editor (Standalone Input), it could get you a different value even if x and y are the same.

Another possibility is that there is a platform specific error happening somewhere else in the code, upon object instantiate. Your movement code would still work fine, if it isn't in the same Monobehavior.

If you have an Android, you can use [Android Monitor](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/android-monitor.html) with the Unity tag to check for error messages.

Comment: Thanks Robert, turned out the Z value was being changed on instantiation. Manually changing it back to 0 worked :)

Comment: Glad to hear I was able to help! :)